# Create a new array adding duplicate values together

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I have a two dimensional array:

```
[[bourbon, 2], [bourbon, 1],[scotch, 2]]
```

I would like to end up with a new array that consolidates the duplicates so that the array would become

```
 [[bourbon, 3], [scotch, 2]]
```

Here is how I create the array:

```
    for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
         var typeW = String(data[i].doc.type);
         var valueAsNumber = parseInt(data[i].doc.bottle);
         typeOfWhiskey[j,i] = [typeW,valueAsNumber];
         j++;
    }
```

I have tried to check for unique values with:`if(typeOfWhiskey.indexOf(typeW ) > -1){`

However I am currently stuck. In this example 'typeW' is the string value for 'bourbon', or 'scotch' for example, where as 'valueAsNumber' would be 2 or 1 based on the example provided.   I would like to not have to create another for look and iterate through the whole array again because I feel that would be inefficient.  I think I am close but am not sure how to proceed.  Thanks

Comment: What do you think `typeOfWhiskey[j,i] ` is doing?

Comment: @FelixKling it is allowing me to construct the array.  j and i increment as I more through the array where I get the values causing typeOfWhiskey to be built.

Comment: Mmh.... `typeOfWhiskey[j,i]` is eqivalent to `typeOfWhiskey[i]`. `j,i` is the comma operator at work, so the whole expression evaluates to `i`. You might want `typeOfWhiskey[j][i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
var source = [['bourbon', 2], ['bourbon', 1],['scotch', 2]];
var hash = {};
var consolidated = [];

source.forEach(function(item) {
     hash[item[0]] = (hash[item[0]] || 0) + item[1];
});

Object.keys(hash).forEach(function(key) {
     consolidated.push([key, hash[key]]);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4y80m3w6/)

Answer (score 1):

Create a copy of initial array.

I did something similar recently, this might help:

```
// Create copy to delete dups from
$copy = $sowArray; 
$sharedDescriptions = array();

for( $i=0; $i<count($sowArray); $i++ ) {
    if ( in_array( $sowArray[$i][$description], $sharedDescriptions ) ) {
        unset($copy[$i]);
    }
    else {
        $sharedDescriptions[] = $sowArray[$i][$description];
    }
}
$sharedDescriptions = array_values($sharedDescriptions);
$copy = array_values($copy);

// Update quantities of duplicate items
for( $i=0; $i<count($copy); $i++ ) {
    $product = $copy[$i][$description];
    $qty = 0;
    if (in_array($product, $sharedDescriptions)) {
        foreach ($sowArray as $sowRow) {
            if ($sowRow[$description] === $product){
                $qty += $sowRow[$quantity];
               }
            }
        $copy[$i][$quantity] = $qty;
        } 
    }
```